# Preserve input file format with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to process hundreds of fairly large CSV files. Each file contains 4 header lines followed by 864000 lines of data and weight more than 200 Mo. Columns type are most of the time recognized as object because missing values are indicated as `"NAN"` (with quotes). I want to perform couple of operations on these data and export them to a new file in a format similar to the input file. To do so, I wrote the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv(in_file, skiprows=[0,2,3])

# Get file header
with open(in_file, 'r') as fi:
    header = [next(fi) for x in range(4)]

# Write header to destination file
with open(out_file, 'w') as fo:
    for i_line in header:
        fo.write(i_line)
        
# Do some data transformation here
df = foobar(df)

# Append data to destination file
df.to_csv(out_file, header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

I struggle to preserve exactly the input format. For instance, I have dates in the input files formated as `"2019-08-28 00:00:00.2"` while they are written in the output files as `2019-08-28 00:00:00.2`, i.e. without the quotation marks.
Same for `"NAN"` values that are rewritten without their quotes.Pandas wants to clean everything out.
I tried other variants that worked, but because of the file size, running time was unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Include quoting parameter in to_csv i.e. `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC or quoting=2`

so your to csv statement will be as follows:

```
df.to_csv(out_file, header=False, index=False, mode='a', quoting=2)
```

Note: you need to import csv if you want to use csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

More details about the parameters can be found on the documentation (below): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: When using quoting=2, negative values are considered non numeric and are therefore quoted in the exported csv. (interesting parameter nonetheless)